# Send a file in python

Tags: python, file, tcp, send

I have looked every where on the net on how to send a file in python, 100% is a fail, no one can help. Are there any programmers out there that can help me send a file from client to server or the other way?

I can send txt very easy

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""
Socket Client
"""
import socket #networking library
indent = ""
server = input("server name (default is " + socket.gethostname() + "): ") or socket.gethostname()

print("connecting to server at: %s" % server)

while True:
    clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

    clientSocket.connect((server, 23000)) 



    str = input("text to send: ")

    clientSocket.send(str.encode("utf-8")) #send text as encoded bytes

    print("received: %s" % clientSocket.recv(100).decode("utf-8")) 

    clientSocket.close()

    #strRecv = clientSocket.recv(500).decode("utf-8") #receive up to 500 bytes and decode into text
    #print(strRecv)
```

Comment: I would like the client side and server side so I can send a file. I would like to open a file. Break it down to pieces in a loop. Send each piece an compile it. Isn't that how it works, well that's why I am here. If I knew how to do it I wouldn't be here

Comment: So you just don't know how to open and read a file?

Comment: I am building an assignment for my Tafe class, thank you for you rhelp, I can work out the rest.. Thanks Matthias aswell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Very* basic example:

#### Server to receive a file:

```
import socket
with socket.socket() as s:
    s.bind(('',8000))
    s.listen(1)
    with s.accept()[0] as c:
        chunks = []
        while True:
            chunk = c.recv(4096)
            if not chunk: break
            chunks.append(chunk)
    with open('out.txt','wb') as f:
        f.write(b''.join(chunks))
```

#### Client to send a file:

```
import socket
with socket.socket() as s:
    s.connect(('localhost',8000))
    with open('myfile.txt','rb') as f:
        s.sendall(f.read())
```